# How do I disable cache in Safari 11.0?

Tags: safari, settings

I updated Safari today to 11.0 and the 'disable cache(s)' menu item (under Develop) is missing. Anyone know the new way to effect this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As [Adam has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333335/3914225) there was information about disable caches added to the release notes, and I've updated my answer accordingly:

---

1. For a one-off, you can use <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on the page to reload from origin or <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> from Web Inspector.
2. For a more permanent solution, you can tell Safari to ignore cache when loading resources by opening Web Inspector then going to the Network tab and setting the [image: ignore the resource cache] icon in the top right (it turns blue when active).

---

After experimentation with the [image: ignore the resource cache] option in the Network tab, it doesn't appear to behave as documented in the release notes:

- The setting appears to persist until manually disabled, even when quitting Safari.
- Caching appears to be disabled for all pages, not just the inspected one.
- Web Inspector didn't always need to be left open.
- Resources served from localhost are sometimes still served from the memory cache, even if caching is disabled in the Network tab. Restarting Safari seemed to clear this behaviour.

---

### Safari Technology Preview Release Notes (Release 27)

#### Browser Changes

- Added a “Reload Page From Origin” alternate menu item to the View menu. This action reloads a page without using cached resources.
- Removed the Option-Command-R (⌥⌘R) keyboard shortcut from “Enter/Exit Responsive Design Mode” and mapped it to “Reload Page From Origin” instead.
- Removed the Disable Caches menu item in the Develop menu. The equivalent functionality is now available through Web Inspector’s Network tab.

#### Web Inspector

- Added “Disable Caches” toggle in the Networking tab that only applies to the inspected page while Web Inspector is open.

---

## Safari 11.1

The appearance of the icon has changed slightly in Safari 11.1:

[image]

Comment: Take particular note of the last bullet "Resource served ..." — this seems to be a major bug that will result in resources simply refusing to reload until starting a new tab/window. Additionally, cmd-shift-R will permanently grey any current breakpoint locations until a new tab/window, while opt-click reload does not.

Comment: Still have the issue. safari keeps serving file from memory when inspecting from connected touch device. Even with the icon in blue, even after restarting safari. safari sucks.

Comment: There's a bug in Safari whereby resources which use `preload` will always be served from memory cache, regardless of settings. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193533

Comment: Can confirm it's april 2021 and this behaviour is still the same on mobile Safari. Connected the iPhone simulator, toggled the 'Use the resource cache when loading resources' button on the network tab and *some* resources are always loaded fresh but Javascript resources still display '(memory)' and aren't reloaded on a refresh.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like (according to the “[Safari Technology Preview Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/)”) that the only way is to open the “Web Inspector” and go the the “Network” tab, and click the small button to ignore the resource cache.

[image: Screenshot of how to disable cache for a page]

Comment: This is a much better solution than the one accepted.

Comment: Is there no way to do this _without_ having the inspector menu open?!? This is going to drive me NUTS.

Comment: I just realized this setting persists even when the inspector is closed (and for all pages). Unintuitive as heck, but does what I want! I just hope Apple doesn't change it later...

Answer (score -1):

From my testing on Safari 11.0.3, you should restart Safari after toggling "Ignore the resource cache when loading resources".

Comment: Where is this option?

Comment: See [adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333335/9564793) @trss

Comment: This should be a comment on one or more existing answers, it is not an answer by itself.

Comment: @colonelclick No enough reputation to comment other's answers.

Comment: ah yeah, i forgot about that :(

Comment: for me its not helping. still have the cache