# Bust Cache with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

When I *don't* use `mix.version()`, my CSS + JS is cached - meaning a refresh does not use newest compiled assets. However, reading Laravel's docs, they state the following:

> Because versioned files are usually **unnecessary in development**, you
>   may instruct the versioning process to only run during npm run
>   production

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

How else would I bust the cache every time my local files changes?

Comment: Do you use chrome? In the developer tools under the "Network" tab, you can disable the cache

Comment: Please also note that **the cache is only disabled while developer tools is open.**

Comment: for some reason after adding/removing mix.version() Chrome starts serving fresh files, even though mix.version() is no longer present... anyone knows how that works ?

Comment: Well either use version or force refresh the cache (You can use ctrl+F5)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the Developer Tools in Chrome, I clicked *Disable Cache*, and it did just that.

**Firefox:** https://dzone.com/articles/how-turn-firefox-browser-cache

**Safari:** [How do I disable cache in Safari 11.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324675/how-do-i-disable-cache-in-safari-11-0)

Comment: You can't do this for every client

Comment: Most browsers allow you to disable the cache. Please remove you downvote.

**Firefox:** https://dzone.com/articles/how-turn-firefox-browser-cache

**Safari:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324675/how-do-i-disable-cache-in-safari-11-0

Comment: This is for development, so is the question. Valid answer IMO but could be more complete

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post. But the convenient solution for the problem is to set new request for every page load. i usually handle this by adding random id in css link.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') . "?id=" . Str::random(16) }}">`

this way will give you uncached css, because the link is always change.