# detach() then append() <picture> tag causes Safari to download same JPG file twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*Max OS version: 10.14.3*

*Safari version: Version 12.0.3 (14606.4.5)*

I am facing a Safari only problem.

I use jQuery to detach() then append() one picture tag, which causes Safari to request the same image twice. That is not expected. And there is no such problem in Chrome and Firefox.

I did a demo in Github for your better understanding.
https://github.com/EdmondWang/picture-tag-on-safari/tree/master

And this is the network panel of demo, you can see the JPG request of "toyota-prius-D@1x.jpg" is sent each time I click the button "move to red" and "move to blue".
[image]

This is snapshot of whole request&response:
[image]
This is log of local node express app:
[image]

Why I am struggling this problem is because we found image get reloaded each time our user swipe the [slick carousel@1.6.0](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in Safari. And I found that
it is because there are detach()&append() logic during swipe action.(the slickAdd method below) So I tried to mock the logic to reproduce the problem.
[image] 
Does anybody know how to avoid this duplicated HTTP request?

Comment: i can't reproduce your issue on safari `Version 12.0.3 (14606.4.5)` :/

Comment: @Yanis-git, you may try  https://github.com/EdmondWang/picture-tag-on-safari/tree/master

Comment: How are you verifying the duplicate request exactly? With the developer tools or the server logs?

Comment: Also check if you disabled the cache in safari. Refer to ths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324675/how-do-i-disable-cache-in-safari-11-0

Comment: @JensV, please see the picture I just uploaded. I think cache is working on my local Safari And each of request is saying 304.

Comment: have you tried $().detach().appendTo() ?

Comment: Am I mistaken or does the request information say that the source is "Memory Cache" meaning that it actually did load from the cache?

Comment: The easiest way to verify this is to log all requests in your node app and checking if it actually gets called

Comment: @FaizanRupani, has updated the reason of asking this question.

Comment: @JensV, agree, uploaded the node log

Comment: In the developer console, can you show the whole response information (headers)? If the server responded with `304` it normally shouldn't respond with the image. It's just the browser checking with the server if the resource has changed. Why this behavior differs from other browsers, I don't know...

Comment: You may be able to control this further by using Cache-Control headers. This is outlined a bit further here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: @JensV , thanks for the advice, I am on the way go home now, will upload response info later.

Comment: Instead of <picture> tag, using a <img> tag will not has this problem.

Comment: @JensV, you are right. Set max-age inside cache-control header of image response will avoid such duplicated request. I may need to check how to set this in our static asset server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jensv, setting `max-age` of `Cache-Control` inside response of image request as any value greater than 0 resolves duplicated http image request in Safari.